# How does d-prime calculation relate to binomial mixed models with probit link?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, probit, signal-detection

for a study I tested participants in a same-different task (1AFC) about melodies. There were 3 versions of each melody (within-subjects factor "version").

So d-prime seems the natural response/dependent variable.

I found a solution by user Mike Lawrence that seems quite elegant:
[How do I compare d-prime scores for 2 different conditions for the same individual?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16576/how-do-i-compare-d-prime-scores-for-2-different-conditions-for-the-same-individu)

```
fit = glm(
  data = my_data, 
  formula = response ~ reality*condition, 
  family = binomial)
```

So in my case I could do the model:

```
response ~reality * version + (1|participant) + (1|melody)
```

Below in the comments user Mike Lawrence states that with a probit link the estimates for the interactions with reality become d-prime units. I don't quite understand why this is the case and how this relates to the transformation that traditionally is done to calculate the d-prime.

**What I don't understand is:**

- How is it that the coefficients for the interaction reality * version (but not those for the main effect of reality) represent differences in d-primes? The model takes not only hit rate and false alarm-rate, but by the effect of reality on response all four possibilities (hit, miss, false alarms, correct rejections), doesn't it?
- Interpretation of the model: If the interaction reality * version corresponds to differences in d-prime, would that mean I basically don't care about the reference category in the factor reality but treat the interaction as if it would be a main effect of version? That is I only look at the reference category of version (say version1) and could then interpret an estimate of 0.3 for reality*version(2) as an increase of sensitivity (d-prime) by 0.3 z-scores?
- And if I wanted to estimate the bias (c) where would that be represented in the model then?

Please excuse if my questions are confusing.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just noticed that different(response)~same(reality)*version(2) actually is the false alarm rate...since reality is whether the signal is present and response is what the participants said. So the signal is absent but they say it was present, thus this is a false alarm. Sorry for that.